# Is it OK if I add a duplicated option when calling an alias for rm?

Tags: bash, alias, rm, options

I have `alias rm='rm -i'` in `.bashrc`.

Now, if I use `rm -i` by mistake, it will become `rm -i -i`.
Would anything go wrong because of two same options?

Comment: Surely quicker to try it on a gash file than to ask the question ?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it will work just fine.

Nothing will go wrong, it will work ok, as `rm` ignores extra (redundant) options which I tested with this simple set of commands:

```bsh
$ touch XY

$ rm -i -i -i XY
rm: remove regular empty file 'XY'? y

$ ls XY
ls: cannot access 'XY': No such file or directory
```

Comment: It doesn't really ignore the related options, it just ends up actioning them (setting the same flag) multiple times. For example `nocase=1; nocase=1; nocase=1` is a redundant version of the simple `nocase=1`. There's no harm, it's just pointless

Comment: @roaima Please feel free to edit my answer to clear that up. Cheers